# Meteor.js ERROR while processing web application to local server

Tags: javascript, meteor

Began testing my web application using Meteor.js on a local host server and the terminal displays multiple errors. All of which state that:

> > "`<body>`declarations have conflicting values for the 'class'
> >     attribute in the following files:"
>
> *file 1.html*,
>
> *file 2.html*

The Meteor documentation does not explain what this error means, and I myself am a bit confused as to what it means. Could someone please clarify to me as to what this error means. An example would also be nice as I am quite a beginner when it comes to programming using JavaScript frameworks.

Thank you :)

Comment: I am using multiple CSS files and multiple HTML files in my project, where certain HTML files have links to certain CSS files

Comment: Can you show the contents of one of the html files?

Comment: You don't need to use the `<body>` tag in .html files.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you shouldn't be using the `<body>` tag in Meteor in more than one file. File1.html should import file2.html with a template import. As follows:

File1.html

```
<body>
  <h1>welcome to my app</h1>
  {{> mytemplate}}
</body>
```

File2.html

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  <p>My lovely app is lovely</p>
</template>
```

This will display as follows:

## welcome to my app

my lovely app is lovely

You should go through the Meteor tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app